# Kernel driver signing

Tags: windows, windows-7, kernel, driver, signing

I have done a great deal of looking around, and I can't seem to get a straightforward answer to this issue.

I am hobbyist programmer, I have done a great deal of work with windows drivers, and wrote my own personal 'antivirus' driver for windows XP. So don't get me wrong here, I don't work for any software development firm or anything of the like.

My question is: as far as windows 7 x64 is concerned, is there any possible **legit and legal** method I can use to release sign my driver that would only be for my own personal use?

Yes I am well aware I can test sign my driver and run it in a virtual machine under windows test mode, which I do quite frequently. However if you have used windows in test mode you know there are some major drawbacks.

So to to sum this all up, is it possible for me ( a hobbyist ) to release sign a driver for my own personal use and not have to deal with windows test mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a boot time required driver, I don't think there is a way you can get it to use it without signing it with a certificate from a Microsoft sanctioned provider (Verisign only I think for drivers?).

If this is a normal device driver that isn't required at boot you can create your own certificates and use those instead. I did it myself for Vista x64 to get an HP ScanJet driver to work from XP x64 by signing the .sys and the .inf files.

I used Active Directory Certificate Services on my domain to issue a Code Signing certificate for my use and had my machine trust the ADCS CA certificate. These two actions will cause Windows to trust your signed driver.

I believe you could use OpenSSL to create a CA certificate and issue code signing certificates with that, but I've had no practice with it.

Again, to reiterate, if this driver is required **at boot** then this method will not work, if it's used for a device which can be attached at anytime, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the [ReactOS Foundation](http://www.reactos.org/) do it for you.

Please refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11649355/744588) to this post: [Windows 7 kernel driver signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335138/windows-7-kernel-driver-signing).

Answer (score -1):

> So to to sum this all up, is it possible for me ( a hobbyist ) to release sign a driver for my own personal use and not have to deal with windows test mode?

Yes.

For boot time drivers: Go to VeriSign, buy the (only?) code signing certificate ($500), and sign your driver.

For non-boot drivers: You can self-sign, with appropriate warnings.

Comment: Thats strange, I have had several people tell me that you need to hold a business license to do so and they even conduct checks on the income of your business? Unless that is pure bs.

Comment: In my experience, by not using an actual "self-signed certificate" but instead having a code signing certificate issued by a CA trusted by the machine (my own CA on Windows Server 2008) I was able to boot and install the driver normally with no end user warnings at all, nor did I have to disable driver signing on boot.

Comment: @Joshua: This is correct. The "required at boot time" is not synonymous with "loaded at boot".