# Windows 7 kernel driver signing

Tags: windows-7, driver, 64-bit, signing

I am an individual, not a company. I am well aware that I can test sign a driver and run in test mode. However myself and the other person on the project are interested in getting our module signed.

Question is: it looks like verisign requires you to be an actual business. Is there anyway we can get a signature through globalsign or something? As an individual developer. Under the windows 7 x64 OS?

Or is it just a big screw you to the individual?

Answer (score 0):

Why not register a sole proprietorship business.  Is that sufficient for Verisign, or do you have to be incorporated.  In my area, both requite payment, but aren't that expensive.  A sole proprietorship is only $80, while incorporating is $300.  Of course these amounts are just examples, and will vary greatly from place to place.

Comment: The *world* speaks English, not just the US ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [ReactOS Foundation](http://www.reactos.org/) can do it for you under somes [conditions](http://www.reactos.org/wiki/Driver_Signing).

As of the time of posting, the following open source projects benefited from that:

- [DiskCryptor](http://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page/en)
- [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)
- [ReiserFS](http://www.acc.umu.se/~bosse/)
- [USB/IP Project](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/)