# Do I need a company for kernel driver signing?

Tags: kernel, code-signing, digital-certificate

Is there a way to get a certificate so sign a kernel driver as an individual developer?

I know it was already asked here: [Windows 7 kernel driver signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335138/windows-7-kernel-driver-signing)
but there isn't a right answer

Comment: Yes, you need a company that can be investigated and verified is required for the certificate that is necessary for kernel drivers. You can form your own company, but it's going to have to have been in existence for some time and have verifiable information (banking and financial records, a legal address, etc.) before the cert is issued by a company that MS will accept for code-signing kernel drivers.